# How do i do this special ripple effect in buttons?

Tags: android, ripple

I saw a special **ripple effect** in an app, i want to do it, too now. I attached a **[video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4AsBzafGgY8bHdqNnVrYy1tN0k/view?usp=docslist_api)** to this **ripple effect**.

Any ideas or suggestions how I can do this?

Comment: Got this on your link: "You need permission

Want in? Ask the owner for access, or switch to an account with permission. Learn more"... Please find another way to share

Comment: Ouh sorry, my mistake, i updated the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [library](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect)  for that 
And wrap your view inside it

```
<com.andexert.library.RippleView
  android:id="@+id/more"
  android:layout_width="?android:actionBarSize"
  android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/more2"
  android:layout_margin="5dp"
  rv_centered="true">

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

</com.andexert.library.RippleView>
```